# Rails: Hide Url for a link_to when users inspect element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a field in my form where users can put their facebook page for example and in my show page I have a button that redirect users to this facebook page but I want when user Inspect element the URL of the facebook page will be hidden now i have a code like this when I inspect element with Mozilla `<a class="btn btn-default" target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com"></a>` but I want the the facebook URL to be hidden

Comment: When you say inspect element, do you mean inspecting the element via a browser developer tool? e.g., Firebug, Chrome Developer Tools

Comment: Yes via a browser developer tool

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. It is impossible to have something people can  click on but which the user can't tell the destination of before clicking. You can make it more or less hassle, but the ultimately the browser has to know, and the browser isn't interested in deceiving the user.